# How do I create a binary dataframe from a categorical trait dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

Please help me code a piece of R code that can convert the following dummy DF with categorical traits into a DF that has all those traits (the actual variables) as columns with a binary indication if these traits were present in the original DF. Only keeping the stations as the first column to look something like the second DF (clumsy) code:

```
categorical_data <- data.frame(
station = rep(1:3, each = 3),
trait1 = rep(c("TraitA", "TraitB", "TraitC"), times = 3),
trait2 = rep(c("TraitX", "TraitY", "TraitZ"), times = 3),
trait3 = rep(c("TraitM", "TraitN", "TraitO"), times = 3)
)
```

Into something like:

```
Binary_data<- data.frame(
station = (1:3),
TraitA = ("1"),
TraitB = ("0")
)
```

It would be fantastic if anyone knows how to do this. Would it be hard to adjust the code to: 1) keep the number of station entries with the relevant 0's and 1's at each trait and 2) collapse the stations into one row per station but returning only 0's and 1's for each trait across the entries for that station?

The original dataframe has some NA's so it would be great if the code could handle that.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I tried some dplyr based solutions, but they all did not go very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach:

```
## create sample categories which actually differ by represented traits:
categorical_data <- data.frame(
  station = rep(1:3, 3),
  trait1 = rep(c("TraitA", "TraitB", "TraitC"), times = 3),
  trait2 = rep(c("TraitX", "TraitY", "TraitZ"), times = 3),
  trait3 = rep(c("TraitM", "TraitN", "TraitO"), times = 3)
)

## > categorical_data |> arrange(station)
##   station trait1 trait2 trait3
## 1       1 TraitA TraitX TraitM
## 2       1 TraitA TraitX TraitM
## 3       1 TraitA TraitX TraitM
## 4       2 TraitB TraitY TraitN
## ...
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

categorical_data |>
pivot_longer(starts_with('trait'), values_to = 'trait') |> ## see (1)
pivot_wider(names_from = trait, values_from = name, 
            values_fn = \(xs) sign(length(xs)),
            values_fill = 0 ## replace NA with 0
            )
```

(1) For other {dplyr} selection helpers than `starts_with` see: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html

output:

```
+ # A tibble: 3 x 10
  station TraitA TraitX TraitM TraitB TraitY TraitN TraitC TraitZ TraitO
    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1       1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
2       2      0      0      0      1      1      1      0      0      0
3       3      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1
```

Comment: Dear I_O, This works brilliantly especially with traits that differ in representation! Maybe you have a another quick solution to another layer of complexity the DF has that I work on. Here the trait columns have names other that trait1, etc. How would you modify the pivot_longer() to select certain coloumns not based on the name? Could potentially be from column 2 to 5 as an example.

Comment: Glad it worked :-) If you have to do "one-hot encoding" (splicing an n-level factor into n binary variables) on a regular base, there's also a number of dedicated functions/how-tos: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=R+one-hot+encoding

Comment: see edited answer for versatile column selection plz

Answer (score 1):

You could `unlist` the traits `by` station and `simplify2array` to get a `cat_mat`, create `trait_uni` and essentially `match` it with with `cat_mat`.

```
> cat_mat <- by(categorical_data[-1], categorical_data$station, unlist) |>
+   simplify2array() |> t()
> 
> trait_uni <- sort(unique(as.vector(cat_mat)))
> 
> bin_data <- `dim<-`(match(cat_mat, trait_uni), dim(cat_mat)) |>
+   apply(1, tabulate, nbins=length(trait_uni)) |> t() |> base::`>`(0) |> 
+   `mode<-`('numeric') |> `dimnames<-`(list(unique(categorical_data$station), trait_uni))
> 
> bin_data
  TraitA TraitB TraitC TraitM TraitN TraitO TraitX TraitY TraitZ
1      1      1      1      0      0      1      0      1      1
2      1      1      1      1      0      1      1      0      0
3      1      1      0      0      1      0      1      1      1
```

---

*Data*

```
categorical_data <- structure(list(station = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), trait1 = c("TraitY", "TraitB", "TraitA", "TraitM", "TraitX", 
"TraitA", "TraitZ", "TraitN", "TraitY"), trait2 = c("TraitZ", 
"TraitO", "TraitA", "TraitA", "TraitM", "TraitB", "TraitY", "TraitN", 
"TraitN"), trait3 = c("TraitZ", "TraitZ", "TraitC", "TraitC", 
"TraitM", "TraitO", "TraitA", "TraitB", "TraitX")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")

## ...and to make it more interesting
set.seed(42)
categorical_data[-1] <- sample(as.matrix(categorical_data[-1]), replace=TRUE)
#   station trait1 trait2 trait3
# 1       1 TraitY TraitZ TraitZ
# 2       1 TraitB TraitO TraitZ
# 3       1 TraitA TraitA TraitC
# 4       2 TraitM TraitA TraitC
# 5       2 TraitX TraitM TraitM
# 6       2 TraitA TraitB TraitO
# 7       3 TraitZ TraitY TraitA
# 8       3 TraitN TraitN TraitB
# 9       3 TraitY TraitN TraitX
```